# branch io data not being received on first install

Tags: android, branch.io

I kept the apk on google drive, used custom url, kept on branch Dashboard.

The deeplink works perfectly fine, initialization is correct as well, however there is no  data receiced when app isn't installed and we need to install manually.

I even tired almost all github comments solution, none work, also tried to force new session, no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

This is on activity

```
    override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    Branch.sessionBuilder(this).withCallback { branchUniversalObject, linkProperties, error ->
        if (error != null) {
            Log.e("BranchSDK_Tester", "branch init failed. Caused by -" + error.message)
            if (error.errorCode == BranchError.ERR_BRANCH_ALREADY_INITIALIZED) {
                val param = Branch.getInstance()
                Timber.tag("BranchSDK_Tester").d("Parms are $param")
            }
        } else {
            handleDeeplink(branchUniversalObject, linkProperties)
        }
    }
        .withData(this.intent.data).init()
}
```

Also tried with latest referring param when session has initialization error.

```
 Branch.getInstance().latestReferringParams
```

There's no required data.

**Fyi**

The initialization is done in application method

```
class MyApp : Application() {

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    Branch.enableLogging()
    Branch.getAutoInstance(this)
    Timber.tag("BranchSDK_Tester").d("branch initialized in my app")
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The flow that you have described is achievable and used by many of our customers, it seems that you might be missing some important integration step. I would suggest creating a support ticket through the [form here](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/page/submit-a-ticket)

Also please add the branch sdk logs retrieved while coming through deferred deeplinking flow (i.e opening the app after downloaded from playstore)